# How to hide JavaScript comments in the resulting HTML page?

Tags: javascript, comments

Is there a way to hide the JS comments on the resulting page source? The JS is generic...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  Just minify your javascript with a tool like JSMin: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

Or UglifyJS: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/
Or Google Closure: https://developers.google.com/closure/

They all strip comments and excess whitespace.  Some will even change your variable names in crazy ways to save bytes.

Or write your JS in a compile to JS language like coffee script http://coffeescript.org/ which strips out comments at compile time.

Comment: Its generic JavaScript, so I cant do that I guess. Any other way?

Comment: "Its generic JavaScript" What is that supposed to mean?  JS can only run when its file has been loaded and parsed, the file with the comments in it.  So how could modify it's own source after it runs? That doesn't make any sense.  Your desire is unclear.

Comment: The JS is created in a PHP file and its values are modified using Prototype, according to some conditions. What I meant is, that I dont have a .js file that I use.

Comment: You could pass it through a javascript minifier in the php script before you output it to the user.

Comment: @user1540714 Huh? You really need to post some code or more details to get more specific help.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up extracting the JS into a .js file so I could use a minifier.