# Is there a way to hide Javascript comments?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript file in which I have put a comment like the following so that it is easy for everyone to understand the code.

```
// This is a good comment
// another good comment
```

But this comment is rendered on the client side which I don't want.
I just want comment for the developers which client should not inspect using the browser. I have tried following too but it didn't work

```
/* This is a good comment
   another good comment */
```

Comment: it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664884/how-to-hide-javascript-comments-in-the-resulting-html-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide JavaScript comments in the resulting HTML page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664884/how-to-hide-javascript-comments-in-the-resulting-html-page)

Answer (score 6):

Since Javascript files are classed as static content they're sent "as is", anything that's contained within them will be sent to the client unless it's specifically removed using some server side script.

One way to achieve this would be to use a minifier that strips out comments, most languages have modules you can use to do this on the fly.

Comment: I wonder why browsers don't filter out the comments in Javascript files by default, they're never intended to be read at the end point.

Comment: @needfulthing Good question. I would say probably because a browser should be neutral, it's not the browser's job to do that and most importantly: it would affect performance.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP on your back-end you can just wrap every comment inside a PHP tag and it then gets removed by the server.

It probably is one of the easiest ways I can think of. 
But it just works when PHP is used. ;)

Comment: This is a perfectly valid reply and would work with any language that preprocesses the js AND where the js is embedded, but often js is in a static file.